# My form is being displayed as text on the page

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I've been building a control panel in Laravel 5.1 and have just built the user administration part of it today.

It seems to be that this happens when I'm using the `Form::` command.

I suspect this because the login and register forms are fine and these come from Auth Scaffolding and so the forms are written out in HTML rather than using the `Form::` command.

However, all the forms I have built using the `Form::` command are just displaying the form code as text on the page.

For example:

```
<h1><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> Add User</h1>

    {{ Form::open(['role' => 'form', 'url' => '/user']) }}

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Name', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
        {{ Form::text('username', null, ['placeholder' => 'Username', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
        {{ Form::email('email', null, ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('password', ['placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', ['placeholder' => 'Confirm Password', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {{ Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Is being displayed on page in plain text as:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/UCP/public/user" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="nlVw9OY28DdLUZKOFcrRnlsc79k0LGOGTfURhhFI">
<label for="name">Name</label> <input placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="name">
<label for="username">Username</label> <input placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name="username" type="text" id="username">
<label for="email">Email</label> <input placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" type="email" id="email">
<label for="password">Password</label> <input placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password" type="password" value="" id="password">
<label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label> <input placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" type="password" value="" id="password_confirmation">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me to get these displayed as forms rather than text on the page?

Comment: Since Laravel 5.0 *all output* is escaped by default, even the one genearated by the form helpers, so you have to explicitly unescape it: `{!! Form::whatever() !!}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment from Quasdunk I solved it, for it to work correctly it needed to be unescaped.

The following code now works a treat:

```
<h1><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> Add User</h1>

    {!! Form::open(['role' => 'form', 'url' => '/user']) !!}

    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Name', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! Form::label('username', 'Username') !!}
        {!! Form::text('username', null, ['placeholder' => 'Username', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email', null, ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', ['placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['placeholder' => 'Confirm Password', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change blade template syntax `{{ Form::blah() }}` to `{!! Form::blah() !!}` that's it.